# Finding in which row a Button was clicked in a GridView/Repeater

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I am binding a `Repeater`. Each row (is that the right word?) in the `Repeater` has a `Button` and a `HiddenField`. How do I determine the Value of the `HiddenField` based on which Button was clicked?

Code behind for Button's `OnClick` event:

```
protected void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnButton1 = (Button)sender;        
    // how do i get this row's HiddenField Value?
}
```

**edit**: the `CommandArgument` suggestion from Pleun works but I am still having issues. I need to find the row(?) in the `Repeater` that the `Button` belongs to as there is also a `TextBox` in each row and I would need its value. So ideally I want to get that row and go FindControl("TextBox1") etc etc. Sorry, should have stated that in my initial question

Comment: this is not related to your question. But if you got the answers to your question/s try accept them. There's an outline of a check mark to the left of each answer :)

Comment: See my updated answer - handle the CommandEvent instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I like to do is add a CommandArgument to the button. In this code its an imagebutton but the idea is the same. So also no need for an extra hidden field.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnMail" ImageUrl="~/imgnew/prof/sendlink.png" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>'
```

And in the _Click event do

```
 string id = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

Update:

If you need all the data, you need a different event. The data in the repeater is available as Item in

```
RepeaterCommandEventArgs
```

in the Command event (RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

for handling the Command event see this example
 http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/custom-buttons-in-the-datalist-and-repeater-cs
or
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatercommandeventargs.aspx

Comment: your welcome, since you are new, please mark as an aswer if it solved your problem.

Comment: what if i needed to retrieve more than one value? i could have many HiddenFields per row, but only one CommandArgument per Control.

Comment: In that do not handle the ButtonClick but the OnCommand event. In RepeaterCommandEventArgs there is your Item with the data you need. More info in the link I posted in an update of the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you using `Repeater` you can identify elements in each row in the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx).

If you using `gridview` use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse upwards by getting the button's Parent, then doing a `FindControl()` on that control.

```
Row parentRow = (Row)((Button)sender).Parent;

var tBox = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)parentRow.FindControl("myTextBox")
```

You may have to play around to see how deep the button is nested and with what control types to get to the appropriate parent.

Answer (score 0):

My markup code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptFiles"  runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                  <td>--</td>
                  <td><%#Eval("title")%></td>
                  <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuVersion" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadVersion" Text="Last opp" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadVersion_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                  </td>
                </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My code behind

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    var documentId = btn.CommandArgument;

    //Get the Repeater Item reference
    RepeaterItem item = btn.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;

    var fuVersion = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("fuVersion");

    var filename = fuVersion.PostedFile.FileName      
}
```